# Instagram API returning permission exception despite proper scope

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I manage an Instagram client that has been approved with scopes `basic` and `public_content`. I'm trying to add the `follower_list` scope as well. Before Instagram's approval, the scope should work in sandbox mode with user=self. I have requested an access token with the `follower_list` permission, but I'm receiving an `OAuthPermissionsException: This client has not been approved to access this resource`.

Logging in to my Instagram account and viewing my Authorized Applications, the client is indeed listed with 'Access your friends list' as a permission. Other restricted endpoints work fine with user=self, such as comments and likes. It seems to just be an issue with the follower_list scope.

Any advice, or is this perhaps a bug on Instagram's part?

Update:

I received the follower_list permission from Instagram, and can now get the followers/followings for `self`. However the API currently does not support retrieving followers for any user other than `self`. So you can access the followers of the logged in user, but no one else.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get logged-in users (self) following list, for this you need `follower_list` permission. You cannot get any other user's following list via API anymore.

Comment: `following_list` is not a valid scope. Per the [API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/), the `follows` and `followed-by` endpoints need the `follower_list` scope. I have that scope, and I am trying to request the followers of `self`, and receiving the OAuth error.

Comment: ya whatever that is `follower_list`, have you been approved for that ?

Comment: With user == self (which is essentially sandbox mode) you do not need approval. This is in fact what you have to use to get a working example and submit for approval.

Comment: (a) for `follows` and `followed-by`, there is only `self`, u cannot put user-id like before June 1,2016. (b) I check in my sandbox, it is working fine for self. Are u really in sandbox mode ?